# call javascript function in init.js when pressing html button

Tags: javascript, html

i have this function in my init.js

```
function bodyresize() {
                        var factor = ($window.width() * $window.height()) / (1440 * 900);
                        $body.css('font-size', Math.min(Math.max(Math.floor(factor * settings.sizeFactor), settings.sizeMin), settings.sizeMax) + 'pt');
                        $main.height(panels[activePanelId].outerHeight());
                        $body._reposition2();
                    };

                    $body._reposition2 = function() {
                        if (skel.vars.isTouch && (window.orientation == 0 || window.orientation == 180))
                            $wrapper.css('padding-top', Math.max((($window.height() - (panels[activePanelId].outerHeight() + $footer.outerHeight())) / 2) - $nav.height(), 30) + 'px');
                        else
                            $wrapper.css('padding-top', ((($window.height() - panels[firstPanelId].height()) / 2) - $nav.height()) + 'px');
                    };
```

now i need from my game1 scrip that when i press a button the code above runs

in my index.html i have this:

```
<head>
<script src="js/init.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

and the button i have this

```
<button id="button" onclick="bodyresize()">Click Me test</button>
```

i think something is wrong with the button because he cant find bodyresize but i cant find why

Answer (score 1):

This is going against your original approach a little bit, but I would handle the entire thing in Javascript. It could look something like this:

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function(e) {
    // your code
}
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/cqhx34Ld/).

**Edit:**

Here's [another example](http://jsfiddle.net/cqhx34Ld/1/) of a button working of `onclick` defined in the element itself. It looks similar to what you originally had.

Both of these approaches are technically correct, but if you define the `onclick` function inside `init.js`, you can't really reuse the file in another page, as the `onclick` function would throw an error when it couldn't find another component of the same name (`button`). A solution around this is define a new file.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: well it kinda did
When i want to go to another .html 
i get this error "onclick" of null and my html doesnt show anything except the background. 

And one more question
When i putt it in the code like this.
 <button id="bodyresize" onclick="showhide()">Click Me</button> 

that it uses the bodyresize and the showhide function on the same time it doesnt work anymore.

Comment: If you run this code on a page that doesn't have an element with id of `button` it will throw an error. I don't have a lot of context as to what else you are trying to do, but you could create another JS file. To address your later concern: make a listener for id `bodyresize`.

Comment: hi the first thing works
right now i can go to the other page. 

but i dont understand make a listener for ide bodyresize

i am not that good in code

Comment: `document.getElementById('bodyresize').onclick = function() {}` It would be close to the same thing. You're just getting the element you want to track `onclick` for and writing a function for it.

Comment: thanks will try that.

but now i still dont understand that if i have a button
that in that same button i can set the showhide wich is in the same script. and that also do bodyresize. just with one button

Comment: that is the only problem i still have

Comment: I'm confused as to what you are asking. Yes, presumably a button could have `onclick` defined in JS and also have a call `onclick="someFunction()"` as well. You can trigger an infinite amount of function calls from an `onclick` event. This goes more into how you as a programmer want to organize and structure your code.

Comment: hi
In my index.html i have a function called showhide() in the init.js i have that function with this code document.getElementById('bodyresize').onclick = function()

But now in my index.html i need a button that first does showhide showhide and then does document.getElementById('bodyresize').onclick = function()

But how do i place that in 1 button